# Backbone Collection not getting models

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone.js-collections

Basically, I'm trying to send a GET request to my Node server, so that I can get back blog posts to create links. I do a `collection.fetch`, which successful completes the GET request (the Node server logs that it's sending the right objects). The model successfully parses the right data, but when I try to use the collection, it says that it's empty. Here's the code:

```
var mdm = mdm || {};

// MODEL
mdm.Post = Backbone.Model.extend({
        parse: function( response ) {
        response.id = response._id;
        console.log(response); // logs the two documents
        return response;
    }
});

// COLLECTION
mdm.Posts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: mdm.Post,
    url: '/api/posts'
});

// MODEL VIEW
mdm.LinkView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template( $('#link_template').html() ),

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ));
        return this;
    }
});

// COLLECTION VIEW
mdm.LinksView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#link_list',

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new mdm.Posts();
        this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
                // makes the request properly, but collection is empty
        this.render();
                // never gets called because the collection is empty
        console.log(this.collection.length); 
                // logs a length of 0
    },

    render: function() {
        // renders collection
    }
});

$(function() {
    new mdm.LinksView();
});
```

The data is being sent and is parsed in the models, so I'm not sure what the collection ends up being empty. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is because `fetch` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason you are not seeing the models in your view is because the render is happening before the asynchronous `fetch` is complete.

Something like below would work better:

```
mdm.LinksView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#link_list',

initialize: function() {
    this.collection = new mdm.Posts();
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    this.collection.fetch({reset: true});
}
```

The above code sets a listener for the `reset` event on the `collection` and executes the `render` function when that happens.

Also, you could passing in `success` and `error` handlers into `fetch` and call the render function manually as well.

```
this.collection.fetch({
    success: _.bind(function() { 
        this.render(); }, this)
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I was able to figure it out, but it's good to see that there are multiple solutions. Is there a reason why you'd prefer one method over the other, or it's a preference thing?

Comment: @EmptyArsenal I prefer the listener method, because its easy to add new ones like `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render)` to re-render after a new model is added and such. I feel backbone is strongest when you leverage events and data-driven actions as opposed to manual transactions. But Backbone is so flexible that anything is fair game :D

Answer (score 0):

Per @fbynite's comment, the problem was related to `fetch` being asynchronous. I made the following changes to the collection view, and it did the trick:

```
initialize: function() {
    var self = this;
    this.collection = new mdm.Posts();
    this.collection.fetch({reset: true,
        success: function() {
            self.render();
            console.log(self.collection.length);
        }
    });
},
```

The code is a modification from a Backbone tutorial, so other users may encounter a similar problem. http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/#exercise-2-book-library---your-first-restful-backbone.js-app